# pynput, key release issue, program tries to repeat the loop for the number of keys pressed rather than stopping when released

Tags: python, pynput

```
from pynput import keyboard

def on_press(key):
    try:
        if key.char == "w":
            func()
        elif key.char == "s":
            func2()
        elif key.char == "d":
            func3()
        elif key.char == "a":
            func4()
```

We have this code to accept keyboard inputs to control a hexapod
when "w" is pressed it loops through the forward sequence.

We would like it to stop at the end of the current loop upon key release, but it doesn't
the loops tries to run for the number of "w" that were printed, so if you hold it 3 seconds it is wanting to loop about 50 times before coming to a stand.

We have tried, amongst other things

```
def on_release(key):
    restart()
    import keyboard as keyboar
    try:
       if( not keyboar.is_pressed('w')\
       or not keyboar.is_pressed('a')\
       or not keyboar.is_pressed('s')\
       or not keyboar.is_pressed('d'))\
       and key.char != "w"\
       and key.char != "a"\
       and key.char != "s"\
       and key.char != "d"\
       and key.char != "r":
```

can anyone see where we're going wrong here?
Thanks

Comment: Having a side-effectual function run every time a key handler is called isn't really a good idea. Ideally, the press handlers sets a flag to true or something, the release sets it to false, and some external function loops while the flag is true. The idea is, the press handler shouldn't trigger further events if one has already been started, or you end up with a backlog of events that need to be run.

Comment: @Carcigenicate thanks for that, we've moved it to flags and still no joy :( now taking a look at a different way with pygame